# What are the limits & capabilities of Op Amps with AC signals?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ac

I have learned about op-amps from Practical Electronics for Inventors and The Art of Electronics, but they do not talk much about op-amps with AC input and output. Maybe I missed it and it was "hidden" in the textbook, but to my comprehension, they did not talk much about it.

I know about DC op-amps, but I want to know how op-amps work with AC.

So my question is, what are the capabilities/limits of op-amps for AC applications?

---

Some things I would like to know (but not limited to):

- What is the maximum frequency an op-amp can amplify?
- Does an op-amp amplify the RMS value of the AC signal or the peak value? Does this apply to both voltage and current?
- When the op-amp receives a negative swing of the signal, does it make it more negative?

And if there is anything else that is important to know, please post it in your comment or answer.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest that you now read: Opamps for everyone: http://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/op_amps_everyone.pdf

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you for that textbook, I will check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Maximum frequency than can be amplified depends on which op-amp you bought. Some go to few kHz, some go to few hundred MHz. They all have some frequency limit and they work up to that limit, listed in datasheet as gain bandwidth product. So the limit depends on how much you amplify.
2. Neither. It amplifies the actual whole signal waveform. You can't just amplify the peak ot RMS, as they are defined by the signal waveform.
3. Yes, if you made the op-amp circuit in such a way that it amplifies negative voltages to even more negative voltages.

Comment: What I am curious about is how engineers amplify 5G signals (24.25 GHz to 52.6 GHz). Do they use op-amps for this? If I were to follow what you said that op-amps can only amplify only to a few hundred MHz, then how do they do it? But I am probably wrong, and there might be some ultra op-amps that can work in the GHz range. Or maybe they use some discrete components to amplify?

Comment: That's not an area for using op-amps any more. Discrete RF capable transistors do exist.

Comment: RF is a special requirement for  simple transistor configurations. While Op Amps have so many that they are unstable with phase shift using negative feedback  and thus made stable by a low pass filter near 10Hz inside so that the gain x  BW is a constant product.